# Get user_name of relative data I read using ::with

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 6 when I read data from ads table I use ::with( to get relative data 
from ad_report_abuses table (has fields id, ad_id, user_id, text ) like"

```
$ads = Ad
    ::with('adReportAbuses')->
    getByTitle($this->filter_title)
    ->getByStatus('A')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ads.creator_id')
    ->orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)

    ->select(
        'ads.*',
        'users.name as creator_username',
        'users.email as creator_email',
        'users.phone as creator_phone'
    )

    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($ads_per_page)
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate($ads_per_page);
```

Which I select with resource :

```
class AdResource extends JsonResource
{
    public static $wrap = 'ads';
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            ...
            'adReportAbuses' => AdReportAbuse::collection($this->whenLoaded('adReportAbuses')),
            ...
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        ];
    }
```

In app/Ad.php model I have :

```
public function adReportAbuses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\AdReportAbuse', 'ad_id', 'id');
}
```

and it works ok and in subarray adReportAbuses I have fields :

```
[0] => ad_id
[1] => user_id
[2] => text
```

, but I also need in adReportAbuses request to get user_name field of 
related adReportAbuses.user_id and that is different relation I have in main request  ad.user_id...
Can I ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question seem very unclear, can you try rephrasing. Especially "in adReportAbuses request" i misunderstand as you have nothing related to requests in this context

Comment: Sorry, I modified. Is it clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you just need to modify your AdReportAbuse Resource, to include the user. This should be achieveable by firstly adding the relation to the AdReportAbuse model.

```
class AdReportAbuse {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

In the AdReportAbuse Resource.

```
public function toArray() {
    // load the user from the adAbuseReport
    'user' => new UserResource($this->user),
}
```

Now your response will include Ads with many AdAbuseReports that has a single user. For performance you can update your with() call. Your are joing data into your Ad model, this approach can similar avoid that, most of the times joining data in Laravel is an anti pattern.

```
::with('adReportAbuses.user')
```

Comment: I think i understand so far, see if i am on the right track and let's talk about it :)